# Onclick value to form value in html

Tags: html, forms, onclick

I have 92 value for `<input type="hidden" name="location">`

- i can use drop down or other method but it hard to select in drop down
- so i displayed all value in rows and colum

how can i make Onclick value to  form input????

- and i need to display the selected value

how can i have hidden form value by click method to form value

```
USA         india     china 
austria     japan     koera
```

on click to form value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<span class="country">USA</span>
<span class="country">India</span>

<input type="hidden" name="country" id="country" />
```

Then jQuery

```
$('.country').on('click', function() {
    $('#country').val( $(this).text() );
});
```

If you need to populate the form with a country code instead of a name you could do this:

```
<span class="country" data-code="us">USA</span>
<span class="country" data-code="in">India</span>

<input type="hidden" name="country" id="country" />
```

Then jQuery

```
$('.country').on('click', function() {
    $('#country').val( $(this).data('code') );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the HTML.

jQuery:

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    $(this).closest('form').find('input:hidden').click();
});
```